# @Patch decorator is not compatible with pytest fixture

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, fixtures

I have encountered something mysterious, when using patch decorator from mock package integrated with pytest fixture.

I have two modules:

```
    -----test folder
          -------func.py
          -------test_test.py
```

in func.py:

```
    def a():
        return 1

    def b():
        return a()
```

in test_test.py:

```
    import pytest
    from func import a,b
    from mock import patch,Mock

    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    def brands():
        return 1


    mock_b=Mock()

    @patch('test_test.b',mock_b)
    def test_compute_scores(brands):                 
         a()
```

It seems that patch decorate is not compatible with pytest fixture. Does anyone have a insight on that? Thanks

Comment: I had a similar issue, i was importing ```from unittest.mock import patch``` as well as  ```import mock``` , i had to remove the import mock statement, then is stopped throwing ```fixture 'mocked_instance' not found``` errors

Comment: I would suggest you switch the accepted answer.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I had the same problem and solution for me was to use mock library in 1.0.1 version (before I was using unittest.mock in 2.6.0 version). Now it works like a charm :)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have this problem when using mock library 1.0.1

Answer (score 150):

When using pytest `fixture` with `mock.patch`, test parameter order is crucial.

If you place a fixture parameter before a mocked one:

```
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch('my.module.my.class')
def test_my_code(my_fixture, mocked_class):
```

then the mock object will be in `my_fixture` and `mocked_class` will be search as a fixture:

```
fixture 'mocked_class' not found
```

But, if you reverse the order, placing the fixture parameter at the end:

```
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch('my.module.my.class')
def test_my_code(mocked_class, my_fixture):
```

then all will be fine.

Comment: This is the solution and not the one by Konrad.

Comment: This should be the solution

Comment: Did not work for me for a test method inside a class

Comment: As an alternative you can use a with block. That will work inside classes, too. Also see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Hopefully this answer on an old question will help someone.

First off, the question doesn't include the error, so we don't *really* know what's up. But I'll try to provide something that helped me.

If you want a test decorated with a patched object, then in order for it to work with pytest you could just do this:

```
@mock.patch('mocked.module')
def test_me(*args):
    mocked_module = args[0]
```

Or for multiple patches:

```
@mock.patch('mocked.module1')
@mock.patch('mocked.module')
def test_me(*args):
    mocked_module1, mocked_module2 = args
```

pytest is looking for the names of the fixtures to look up in the test function/method. Providing the `*args` argument gives us a good workaround the lookup phase. So, to include a fixture with patches, you could do this:

```
# from question
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def brands():
    return 1

@mock.patch('mocked.module1')
def test_me(brands, *args):
    mocked_module1 = args[0]
```

This worked for me running python 3.6 and pytest 3.0.6.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is about mixing pytest fixtures and patches in the method signature, not just patches.

Comment: I've added the bit about the fixtures that completes the answer to the question. I'd say its a tad hacky but it works. Thanks @zalpha314 for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6):

As of **[Python3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock)**, the `mock` module has been pulled into the `unittest` library. There is also a backport (for previous versions of Python) available as the standalone library `mock`.

Combining these 2 libraries within the same test-suite yields the above-mentioned error:

```
E       fixture 'fixture_name' not found
```

Within your test-suite's virtual environment, run `pip uninstall mock`, and make sure you aren't using the backported library alongside the core unittest library. When you re-run your tests after uninstalling, you would see `ImportError`s if this were the case.

Replace all instances of this import with `from unittest.mock import <stuff>`.

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple patches to be applied, order they are injected is important:

```py
# from question
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def brands():
    return 1

# notice the order
@patch('my.module.my.class1')
@patch('my.module.my.class2')
def test_list_instance_elb_tg(mocked_class2, mocked_class1, brands):
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't address your question directly, but there is the [pytest-mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-mock) plugin which allows you to write this instead:

```
def test_compute_scores(brands, mock):                 
     mock_b = mock.patch('test_test.b')
     a()
```

Answer (score 1):

**a)** For me the solution was to use a `with` block inside the test function instead of using a `@patch` decoration before the test function:

```
class TestFoo:

    def test_baa(self, my_fixture):
        with patch(
            'module.Class.function_to_patch',
            MagicMock(return_value='mocked_result')
        ) as mocked_function_to_patch:
            result= my_fixture.baa('mocked_input')
            assert result == 'mocked_result'
            mocked_function_to_patch.assert_has_calls([
                call('mocked_input')
            ])
```

This solution **does work inside classes** (that are used to structure/group my test methods). Using the `with` block, you don't need to worry about the order of the arguments. I find it more explicit then the injection mechanism but the code becomes ugly if you patch more then one variable. If you need to patch many dependencies, that might be a signal that your tested function does too many things and that you should refactor it, e.g. by extracting some of the functionality to extra functions.

**b)** If you are **outside classes** and **do want a patched object to be injected** as extra argument in a test method... please note that `@patch` **does not support to define the mock as second argument of the decoration**:

```
@patch('path.to.foo', MagicMock(return_value='foo_value')) 
def test_baa(self, my_fixture, mocked_foo):
```

does not work.

=> Make sure to **pass the path as only argument to the decoration**. Then define the return value inside the test function:

```
@patch('path.to.foo') 
def test_baa(self, my_fixture, mocked_foo):
    mocked_foo.return_value = 'foo_value'
```

(Unfortunately, this does not seem to work inside classes.)

**First** let inject the **fixture(s)**, **then** let inject the **variables of the @patch decorations** (e.g. 'mocked_foo').

The **name of the injected fixture** 'my_fixture' needs to be correct. It needs to match the name of the decorated fixture function (or the explicit name used in the fixture decoration).

The **name of the injected patch variable** 'mocked_foo' **does not follow a distinct naming pattern**. You can choose it as you like, independent from the corresponding path of the @patch decoration.

If you **inject several patched variables**, note that the **order is reversed**: the mocked instance belonging to the last `@patch` decoration is injected first:

```
@patch('path.to.foo') 
@patch('path.to.qux') 
def test_baa(self, my_fixture, mocked_qux, mocked_foo):
    mocked_foo.return_value = 'foo_value'
```