# Python Mock.Patch a function used at several places

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest.mock

#### This works:

I got my program:

```
# module/core_functions.py

def new_input(question):
    print(question)
    value = input(">").strip()
    return value


def main_function():
    #do things
    new_input("question1")
    #do other things
    new_input("question2")
    ...
```

I wrote an unittest:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from module.core_functions import main_function

class MytestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('module.core_functions.new_input')
    def test_multiple_answer(self, mock_input):
        mock_input.return_value = Mock()
        mock_input.side_effect = ['Answer1', 'Answer2']
        result = main_function()
        self.assertIn('ExpectedResult', result)
```

This works perfectly fine (I use `nose2` to run all my tests).

#### Now this is not working:

As my code is getting bigger and bigger, I would like to involve other people in my project and I need to modularise my functions to make modification easier and cleaner.

So I put the `new_input` function in a new file `module/io.py` and I got a new subfunctions:

```
# module/subfunctions.py
from module.io import new_input

def subfunction():
    # do things
    new_input("question")
    # do things
    return things
```

And my core program evolved to:

```
# module/core_functions.py
from module.io import new_input
from module.subfunctions import subfunction

def main_function():
    #do things
    new_input("question1")
    #do other things
    subfuntion()
    ...
```

So the problem is that **the function to mock is in several places**: in the main function and in some subfunctions.
I can't find a way to have my unittest working (I can't predict if AnswerX will be needed in the main function or in one subfunction).

Do you have any idea how can I fix my test so it works?
Thank you (I hope I've been rather clear).

#### Edit:

I tried something like:

```
@patch('module.core_functions.new_input')
@patch('module.subfunctions.new_input')
def test_multiple_answer(self, mock_input):
    mock_input.return_value = Mock()
    mock_input.side_effect = ['Answer1', 'Answer2']
    result = main_function()
    self.assertIn('ExpectedResult', result)
```

But I got the error: `TypeError: test_multiple_answer() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

Comment: There's no way around it - you'll have to mock the function wherever it is called.

Comment: I tried it (see my edit in first post), but I don't know how to handle it after.

Comment: For each patch you're adding you also need to add an argument to your test function. Alternatively, you can add a patch with an object in place which won't require an argument: @mock.patch('target.function', mock.MagickMock(return_value='answer2'))

Answer (score 6):

I just asked myself the same question, and while I was pretty certain of the answer, I wrote a stupidly small but understandable proof of concept.

Like @whats-done-is pointed out there are two ways to go about this; either specify the mock objects to inline using `mock.patch()`'s **new** argument, or add a parameter for each @patch annotation.

#### utils.py

```
def expensive_function():
    return 12345
```

#### module1.py

```
from utils import expensive_function
from module2 import method2

def method1():
    return {'method1': expensive_function(), 'method2': method2()}
```

#### module2.py

```
from utils import expensive_function

def method2():
    return expensive_function()
```

#### main.py

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from module1 import method1

def mock_expensive_function():
    return 123

class TestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_unpatched(self):
        self.assertEqual({'method1': 12345, 'method2': 12345}, method1())

    @patch('module1.expensive_function', new=mock_expensive_function)
    def test_method1_patched(self):
        self.assertEqual({'method1': 123, 'method2': 12345}, method1())

    @patch('module2.expensive_function', new=mock_expensive_function)
    def test_method2_patched(self):
        self.assertEqual({'method1': 12345, 'method2': 123}, method1())

    @patch('module1.expensive_function', new=mock_expensive_function)
    @patch('module2.expensive_function', new=mock_expensive_function)
    def test_both_patched_inline(self):
        self.assertEqual({'method1': 123, 'method2': 123}, method1())

    @patch('module1.expensive_function')
    @patch('module2.expensive_function')
    def test_both_patched_magicmock(self, mock_in_module2, mock_in_module1):
        mock_in_module1.return_value = mock_expensive_function()
        mock_in_module2.return_value = mock_expensive_function()
        self.assertEqual({'method1': 123, 'method2': 123}, method1())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Great poc! A small caveat for the last solution. If we are using pytest, our fixtures must be [included after](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890193/6560773) the magicmocked functions.